# I am using fillo to read excel file from my drive location but it shows unable to find file

Tags: excel, vba

```
Fillo f = new Fillo();
Connection c = f.getConnection("F:\\abc.xlsx");
```

Comment: That means the file is not there ^^. Please have a look into [mcve] and then [edit] and improve your question. Please also include in your tags in which code language you are coding. This code is not VBA.

Comment: Is your F drive mounted and browsable through File Explorer when this runs?